# Union tables with different schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I am referring to Jordan's answer regarding "dealing with evolving schemas "[Dealing with evolving schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609114/dealing-with-evolving-schemas).

As I share similar problem I have tried to query tables with different schema and got the following results:

```
Select a,b,c 
FROM (Select 1 as a, 2 as b), --Test_a
     (Select 1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c), --Test_b
```

runs fine...
I have put Test_a and Test_b into physical tables (all fields are nullable) and tried:

```
 Select a,b,c 
 FROM (Select a,b, from BI_WORKSPACE.Test_a), 
      (Select a,b,c from BI_WORKSPACE.Test_b)
```

It also runs fine

but when i tried

```
 Select a,b,c 
FROM BI_WORKSPACE.Test_a,
     BI_WORKSPACE.Test_b
```

It failed...
Is there a bug, something i do wrong?
the last sample is the one i am after as it allows me to "evolve" my schema over time. i would like to avoid altering schema of all existing tables whenever i add a column to support a new business need.

Many thanks for your help.

The reason for asking:
We hold our data in "Daily tables" so when querying we pay only for the period we are interested in.
As BQ doesn’t support "Dynamic SQL", we have created an offline process that takes a query template and generates a query for desired period. Something like:
Input:

```
Select a,b,c FROM [<Source>]
```

Output:

```
Select a,b,c FROM [MYDATASET.TABLE20140201], [MYDATASET.TABLE20140202], [MYDATASET.TABLE20140203], [MYDATASET.TABLE20140204] , [MYDATASET.TABLE20140205] , [MYDATASET.TABLE20140206] , [MYDATASET.TABLE20140207]
```

Our process is unaware of the query logic. Sometimes we add fields to support evolving business needs. 
Using dynamic sub selects will complicate staff a lot, and altering the schema for all hundreds of existing tables is expensive and prone to mistakes.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the last query *should* work. You're asking for columns a,b, and c from two tables, but one of those tables doesn't have a column with that name. That looks like a query error to me, since you are explicitly asking for a column that doesn't exist on the table.

There is a workaround -- to use a subselect -- which you noticed, if you know that a field may be missing from one schema. The other workaround, of course, is to update the schema.

This seems like it is working as intended. If you don't agree, can you let me know why?

Comment: Thank you Jordan for your answer…
Frankly, I wouldn’t expect the 1st & 2nd to work, but if they do, I would expect the 3rd to work also…
I have edited the question to explain my motivation better.

Comment: Does it make things easier for you to use "(SELECT * FROM [MYDATASET.TABLE20140201])" as your subquery (rather than having to list fields explicitly? This won't change which fields you get billed for accessing, since you don't change the fields that are actually needed in the query.

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work... I tried
Select a,b,c
FROM
(SELECT * FROM [BI_WORKSPACE.Test_a]),
(SELECT * FROM [BI_WORKSPACE.Test_b]),
and recieved Error: Field 'c' not found in table 'BI_WORKSPACE.Test_a';

Comment: The standard SQL ```Select a,b,c
FROM (Select 1 as a, 2 as b union all Select 1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c) ``` would return ```Queries in UNION ALL have mismatched column count;``` error. Is there any workaround for that? We have to use views which aren't supported in Legacy SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to select from union of tables with different schemas.
Simple trick is to use subquery with asterisk as Jordan proposed. There's no need to alter schema.

In your case this will work (legacy SQL dialect)

```
SELECT a,b,c 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM BI_WORKSPACE.Test_a ),
     ( SELECT * FROM BI_WORKSPACE.Test_b )
```

Comment: Isn't that a cartesian product ?

Comment: Back then, when the answer was added the default was the legacy SQL dialect, and there it is union.