# How to "ignore" missing columns in a bigquery table range query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am querying a range of Bigquery tables at a time. However, some of the tables may not have a particular column. Is there a way to tell Bigquery to treat non-existent columns as null columns instead of getting a *Field 'field_name' not found in table* error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to define view for old tables, which will lists all the columns, and produce NULLs for newly added columns, i.e.

```
SELECT a, b, c, CAST(NULL as STRING) d, CAST(NULL AS INTEGER) as e FROM T
```

Answer (score 1):

If you avoid "Select *" and define all specific columns in the select statement, it usually works (as long as the retrieved fields do exist in all specified tables).

also, check this out:
[Union tables with different schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521406/union-tables-with-different-schema)

Comment: I think this is more complex than looks. Suppose there is a table_date_range in the FROM clause and uses Google Analytics table schema, which have changed over the time, and has additional columns here there. It's extremely hard to list all the tables, and actually to know when the new column was introduced.

Comment: Pentium10's use case is very similar to what I want. Sometimes a particular field is left out in a table within a range.